# How to do a GROUP BY operation on a struct

Tags: performance, linq, go, optimization, nested-loops

I have a struct as the following.

```
type resources struct {
   Id int
   Start string
   End string
   Resource map[string][]string
}
```

My data in the struct []resources is as below,

```
1, "2020-04-27T05:30:00","2020-04-27T06:30:00", "{"room":["101","102"], equipments: ["stethescope"]}"
2, "2020-04-27T05:30:00","2020-04-27T06:30:00", "{"room":["102"], equipments: ["thermometer"]}"
```

Now that i need to group by based on start and end time, to get me the desired output as below.

```
"{"room":["101","102"], equipments: ["stethescope","thermometer"]}"
```

I have achieved this by making a for loop but that sounds expensive when dealing with larger data. Is there any other efficient way we can achieve this without looping? I checked this https://github.com/ahmetb/go-linq to implement LINQ for my scenario. Couldn't make it for my struct type.

Comment: https://github.com/ahmetb/go-linq/blob/master/where.go in the library that you specified they are also using a loop to compare..

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I need to know is there an efficient way to avoid nested loops and improvise performance other than LINQ.

Comment: No, you cannot avoid a loop to group your data.

Comment: if its an array of struct then the only way is to iterate and compare..

Answer (score -1):

You could sort your array of resources by start time first.  That way finding the entries you need by start date by binary search would be O(ln base 2) of the array size. See the example of the sort package at https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example__sortKeys

Comment: "finding the entries you need by start date" isn't the goal. Sorting doesn't help, except for very specific aggregation functions (but set union isn't one of them), and even then only if aggregation happens many times because sorting itself is worse than O(n).

Comment: If the array is sorted by start date, operations such as grouping by date will be more efficient.  You're right, I should have mentioned that the sort is probably O(n ln(n)), but you do the sort once, and then you can do multiple queries based on the sorted array.

Comment: You still need to visit every single entry in the list to feed it to the aggregator, sorted or not is irrelevant (again, with some exceptions such as finding extrema): https://play.golang.org/p/FYCqj2VR1kW

Comment: If it's sorted, the aggregator can stream its data, without the need to store the whole collection.